# What is the Single Word for Burning Alive?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, terminology, british-english, synonyms

Is there any single word substitute for 'Burning Alive'? We've Behead for 'Cut off the head'. Similar  way, What is the Single word equivalent for 'Burning Alive' If any?

Comment: Have you used a thesaurus or reverse look up dictionary (like onelook.com) to see if there is a word?

Comment: Are you referring specifically to execution by burning, or burning to death in general?

Comment: @adrian Yes execution by burning.

Comment: My favorite of these terms is "defenestration" - killing someone by throwing them out of a window.

Comment: I thought defenestration was throwing anything out of a window.

Comment: A gruesome and morbid [ordeal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defenestrations_of_Prague#Second_Defenestration_of_Prague); can't grasp the interest.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The word **immolation** has this sense (among others):

*immolate* tr.v.

1. To kill (an animal, for instance) as a religious sacrifice.
2. To kill, especially by fire: "[The soldiers] are crushed under rocks, pierced by bullets, immolated by flamethrowers" (A.O. Scott).

*immolation*  n.

{[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/immolation)} [tidied]

Comment: 1. For instance, at the shrine of Huitzilopochti on top of the temple mayor of Tenochtitlan.

Answer (score 4):

The usual term for this is [**immolation,**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/immolate) derived from the verb **immolate:**

> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> Kill or offer as a sacrifice, especially by burning
>
> EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *Chinese kings would **immolate** vast numbers of animals*
>
> *When her father - who did not accept Shiva, ever - publicly humiliated her beloved at the ritual, Sati **immolated** herself in the sacrificial fire, desecrating it.*
>
> *In the old days, the priests used to **immolate** their sacrifices at the shrine of Huitzilopochti on top of the temple mayor of Tenochtitlan, but we're more civilised than that.*
>
> *Madri **immolates** herself on her husband's funeral pyre.*

(Definition and examples from Oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: -2 sec Serves you right for using big words.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - "Burn!", eh? :)

Comment: See you in Mexico. I take it they've voted in a new mayor.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional word for this is [immolate](http://i.word.com/idictionary/immolate). While this can theoretically mean other types of death, it is nowadays usually understood to involve burning.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore everything I'm about to say!  I made a mistake.

> I'm pretty sure the word is simply "burning" (used in context). 
>    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burning_(disambiguation)
>   Having looked around, no other term is used for the executory incineration of a human.  It wouldn't be too hard to Google this kind of question.

And ignore this, too.

> **Edit:** I have to give respect to Erik Kowal for "Immolation."  However, understand that immolation is used in the sense of "self-immolation."  Execution by fire is not immolation.

More respect to Erik Kowal.  He's a boss.

Comment: *Burning* doesn't imply that the thing being burned is alive. Also, it is not too hard too search for the answer.

Comment: It is correct that the word "Burning" on its own does not imply that the thing being burned is alive.  However, it needs to be used in the proper context, as with almost any word.

Comment: To be fair to other posters here, we all pressed the button on variations of the same answer within seconds of each other. Now, as to your comment that "Execution by fire is not immolation", I'm afraid that is not quite correct: any context in which death is caused by being burned alive can be said to involve *immolation*.

Comment: While that may be true, the term *immolation* is not used to describe this method of execution.  Decapitation **involves** cutting, yet we would not call it execution by cutting.  I will happily redact my assertion if you can find a good example.

Comment: If you run a Google search on *immolation "Jordanian pilot",* you will find plenty of news stories that make reference to the execution by immolation of this most unfortunate person.

Comment: My best understanding of this usage was in regard to human sacrifices.  However, after reading it over again in the context of this discussion, I concede.  Nice job. :)

Answer (score -2):

During the English Reformation "heretics" were ***burned at the stake***. That means they were tied to a stake and a fire lit beneath them.

I have never heard any other term, such as *immolation* used in connection with these executions.

If you go to this YouTube clip you will see the historian Professor David Starkey demonstrating this process to a class of sixth formers (aged 16-18), attending Jamie's (Oliver) Dream School, for children who have hitherto failed. It is not done in a morbid or frightening way, and it is very interesting.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Or3eUymcEA