# What do you call a murderer who burns their victims alive?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology

I promise this isn't as weird as it sounds. I've tried a bit of Googling but I can't find anything that works well.

I'm looking for a single word for a pyromaniac that burns people alive. The question, [What is the Single Word for Burning Alive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225683/what-is-the-single-word-for-burning-alive) it told me about the word "immolation" which is the verb for burning people alive (usually in ritual sacrifices). But I can't find a noun for the person who does it. I would also be fine with some kind of religious term for the priest who performs a burning sacrifice. If all else fails, it can be the person who sacrifices animals if there isn't a word for people.

Comment: You don't like "immolator"?

Comment: I was looking for something a little shorter and that sounds better.

Comment: *Immolate* just means *sacrifice* (usually, by *ritual slaughter*). It has no special association with burning alive as opposed to any other way of killing the "victim, offering".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: immolate meaning 2 = "to kill or destroy often by fire"; for me, the "by fire" is a key portion of the meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was just repeating the answers from the question I linked. My dictionary shows the same as Hellion

Comment: A zoopyrist, someone who burns the living. An anthropopyrist, someone who burns people. A pyrosphagist/pyrophonist, someone who murders with fire.

Comment: Are you asking about someone who sets fire to an apartment building knowing there are people living in it, or about someone who sets fire to an individual?

Comment: @Cerberus Are you sure about those words? I find no mention of them on OED and no Google search results either.

Comment: @Hellion: Okay, I can't deny that ***self-immolation*** - originally almost exclusively used of a (Hindu) widow on her husband's funeral pyre - has pretty strong associations with fire. In fact I think the colonial Brits in India had to pass special laws so aiding & abetting / idly standing by  wasn't defined as a crime.

Comment: @Tim Romano An individual

Comment: @Cerberus a source would be appreciated

Comment: You might use [Cauchon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Cauchon).

Comment: Wouldn't a pyrophagist be a fire eater?

Comment: Trust me, no word for "murderer by fire" is going to "sound better."

Comment: A foreign word would also be acceptable

Comment: @JackGraveney: I have invented them, based on the proper rules of adaptation from Greek (both in form and in meaning). It shouldn't come as a surprise that no such word existed yet!

Comment: @deadrat: Yes, but this is a sphagist, an entirely different root. The Greek roots for murder are phon- (oddly near-identical with the root for "voice, sound"), and less frequently sphag-.

Comment: @Cerberus Thanks.  A trip to the lexicon shows *σφάγιος*, slaughtering, but usually associated with throat slitting.

Comment: @deadrat: True, it is mainly and originally about (throat)-cutting. But I believe it is also used for any kind of killing, see under 5: http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=lsj&lang=el&word=sfa%2fzw&filter=CUTF8 The main reason why I mentioned -sphagist is that people might not like -phonist, which can be confused with phon- "voice".

Comment: @Cerberus Nice catch.

Comment: Depending on your audience, [burninator](https://www.chadly.net/trogdor/) might work. Probably not in a criminology thesis though (altho I don't know many criminologists).

Answer (score 2):

Not really a word, a word, but Immolator would be a good one. As in Vlad the Impalor let me introduce you to Steve the Immolator.

Related: [The Romans had some interesting Latin terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_by_burning)

Comment: Jesus Christ the Romans where awesome. "... the Christian, stripped naked, was forced to put on a garment called the tunica molesta, made of papyrus, smeared on both sides with wax, and was then fastened to a high pole, from the top of which they continued to pour down burning pitch and lard, a spike fastened under the chin preventing the excruciated victim from turning the head to either side, so as to escape the liquid fire, until the whole body, and every part of it, was literally clad and cased in flame."

Comment: @KristinaLopez It's from the article linked in the answer.

Comment: Tunica molesta is Latin for "annoying shirt"